# How do I store the full filename matching a wildcard into a batch file variable?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to write a Windows/DOS batch file for Windows XP, Vista, and Windows 7.  In a given directory, I will have a single file that matches, "selenium*.jar".  How do I store the full file name in a variable and then invoke it in a command?  What I want to do in pseudocode is

```
var FILE=/* Get name of selenium JAR file */
java -jar $FILE -userExtensions user_extensions.js
```

How would I write the above in official DOS batch scripting?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work:

```
FOR %f IN (selenium*.jar) DO java -jar %f -userExtensions user_extensions.js
```

In a batch (.bat) file, you would write `FOR %%f IN ...`.